# Separation of unit tests and integration tests

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, jestjs

I'm interested in creating full mocked unit tests, as well as integration tests that check if some async operation has returned correctly. I'd like one command for the `unit` tests and one for the `integration` tests that way I can run them separately in my CI tools. What's the best way to do this? Tools like mocha, and jest only seem to focus on one way of doing things.

The only option I see is using mocha and having two folders in a directory.

Something like:

- `__unit__`
- `__integration__`

Then I'd need some way of telling mocha to run all the `__unit__` tests in the `src` directory, and another to tell it to run all the `__integration__` tests.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Mocha supports directories, file globbing and test name [grepping](https://mochajs.org/#usage) which can be used to create "groups" of tests.

#### Directories

```
test/unit/whatever_spec.js
test/int/whatever_spec.js
```

Then run tests against all `js` files in a directory with

```
mocha test/unit
mocha test/int
mocha test/unit test/int
```

#### File Prefix

```
test/unit_whatever_spec.js
test/int_whatever_spec.js
```

Then run mocha against specific files with

```
mocha test/unit_*_spec.js
mocha test/int_*_spec.js
mocha
```

#### Test Names

Create outer blocks in mocha that describe the test type and class/subject.

```
describe('Unit::Whatever', function(){})

describe('Integration::Whatever', function(){})
```

Then run the named blocks with mochas "grep" argument `--grep`/`-g`

```
mocha -g ^Unit::
mocha -g ^Integration::
mocha
```

It is still useful to keep the file or directory separation when using test names so you can easily differentiate the source file of a failing test.

#### package.json

Store each test command in your package.json `scripts` section so it's easy to run with something like `yarn test:int` or `npm run test:int`.

```
{
  scripts: {
    "test": "mocha test/unit test/int",
    "test:unit": "mocha test/unit",
    "test:int": "mocha test/int"
  }
}
```

Comment: Using tags on your test description and using the `--grep` feature is also a nice solution. Take a look at https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Tagging.

Answer (score -4):

mocha does not support label or category. You understand correctly.
You must create two folders, unit and integration, and call mocha like this

mocha unit
mocha integration